# How to get the response of calling a redis command

Tags: python

I'm using python 2.6.6 and I can't upgrade.

I had it working fine with subprocess.check_output but I didn't realize we are using python 2.6.6 and I can't upgrade it on my end.

I tried this:

```
command = "redis-cli hget some_key some_field"
command_output = subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0]
```

But I don't think I am passing in the commands correctly, the docs have somethign like:

```
subprocess.Popen( ['ls', 'li'], ..)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yup, you should use lists to give your command line.

```
command = ["redis-cli", "hget", "some_key", "some_field"]
command_output = subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0]
```

Relevant from Moses Koledoye@

> `command.split()` does the conversion to list.

The reason they did this is pretty simple: every argument given will be directly forward to the `redis-cli` program. Let's go in details:

Imagine you have this:

```
key = raw_input("Please give me the key:")
os.system('redis-cli bla bla %s' % key)  # DON'T DO THIS AT HOME.
```

Now imagine I am a malicious guy, and I input the following: `|| echo "hacked by h4x0r"`. The final command will look like this :

```
redis-cli bla bla || echo "hacked by h4x0r"
```

Use list. Really.

Comment: On a side note, as OP has it, `command.split()` does the conversion to list. Might be worth a mention.

Comment: Not a huge fan since it can lead to unexpected behaviors. But yes, worth mentioning in this case :)

Comment: `'a b "hello world"'.split() == ['a', 'b', '"hello', 'world"']` Maybe I didn't understand your comment, but `str.split` only take care of the spaces. EDIT: this is the kind of unexpected behavior you can face.

Comment: ['a', 'b', 'hello world'] was what I wanted, but it turns out I just created the list in the first place I don't need to split since I had all the values in variables lol.